# How to access multiple entities data from a single table type @inheritance table using Thymeleaf in spring boot project?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, thymeleaf, spring-annotations, single-table-inheritance

[link to my project](https://github.com/000GEV744/Spring/tree/master/13-09-19-spring-Inheritance-Employee-demo)
Where I am using single table type inheritance and then using thymleaf , I am trying to access the table's content and trying to put them into a single html page using a single  tag.

Comment: Please provide the code you referring to in your question. Don't think that everyone here wants to go through all your code.

Comment: Please go through this link https://github.com/000GEV744/Spring/tree/master/13-09-19-spring-Inheritance-Employee-demo/src/main/java/com/example/springInheritanceEmployeedemo/entity

Comment: Here you will get my entity classes and this is my controller package https://github.com/000GEV744/Spring/tree/master/13-09-19-spring-Inheritance-Employee-demo/src/main/java/com/example/springInheritanceEmployeedemo/controller

Comment: Please provide a a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE). Linking to other code is discouraged because this site is meant to be an archive and links can go dead or shift. Also, it's unreasonable to ask people to have to dig deep into the structure of your code. Sometimes, I will spend hours writing an MRE to post as a question.